# Unknown attribute "Max-Daily-Session" Freeradius

Tags: freeradius

Im working with a radius application and I'm having issues with Max-Daily-Session. Ive been getting this error "**Unknown attribute "Max-Daily-Session"** requires a hex string, not "3600"

Been looking to many articles related to this issue but I cant figure out what im missing.

This [article](http://freeradius.org/radiusd/man/rlm_counter.html) states that I just have to declare the attributes, but my problem is I dont know where to put or declare it. Ive been looking also into the freeradius dictionary, but cant still solve it. Looking forward for your positive inputs. thanks

Comment: Which version of FreeRADIUS are you using?

Comment: Im using  FreeRADIUS Version 2.1.12. But its all working now, I just added the ATTRIBUTE       Max-Daily-Session       3003    integer in the /etc/freeradius/dictionary. Thanks for your response @ArranCudbard-Bell.

Answer (score 2):

This [article](https://code.google.com/p/fabfi/wiki/IntroductionToRadius) have helped me to solved to issue. I just added the `ATTRIBUTE Max-Daily-Session 3003 integer` in the /etc/freeradius/dictionary.

Comment: v3.0.x versions should automatically add the attribute during module instantiation.  There are many many ordering issues with v2.x.x that have been fixed. Debian just sucks at updating their packages.

Comment: ahh. makes sense., will better upgrade our radius. Thanks for the inputs @ArranCudbard-Bell